# gettext PHP не работает

Tags: php

Скачал пример с использованием gettext: https://github.com/nota-ja/php-gettext-example 
Система: Debian 10
Локали настроены. Вывод

```
locale -a:
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
uk_UA.utf8
```

Но gettext возвращает только ключ. Пробовал много других примеров но все тщетно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные варианты решения.

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался. Еще пример взял отсюда:
http://coddism.com/php/perevod_sajta_s_pomocshju_gettext
По аналогичному вопросу (https://progi.pro/gettext-ne-rabotaet-chto-nepravilno-2705720) добавил строку:

```
putenv('LANGUAGE=ru_RU');
```

И, О ЧУДО, все заработало! Неделя поисков окончена, можно спать спокойно.